# How to convert a void pointer to array of classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, callback

I am trying to convert a void pointer to an array of classes in a callback function that only supports a void pointer as a means of passing paramaters to the callback.

```
class person
{
    std::string name, age;
};
void callback (void *val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (person [])val[i].name;
    }
}
int main()
{
    person p[10];
    callback((void*)p);
}
```

My goal is to be able to pass an array of the class `person` to the callback which then prints out the data such as their name and age. However, the compile does not like what I am doing and complains that `error: request for member 'name' in 'val', which is of non-class type 'void*'` How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Another way to do would be to just pass a pointer to the class which wraps the array of objects. You can have a method in the wrapper which does this printing stuff. From the callback you can just call the member function of the wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to recover the size, you need to use a container which keeps track of the size at runtime. I'd suggest using a std::vector instead of a raw array.

```
std::vector<person> p(10);
static_cast<std::vector<Person>*>(val);
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. What would be the proper way to recover the size from within the callback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to `person *`. Arrays decay into pointers, so casting the void pointer to a `person` pointer works as expected. The clear, more C++, and better way would be:

```
std::cout << static_cast<person *>(val) [i].name;
```

The C way also works, but requires extra parentheses, and is very unsafe/evil when you have the proper casts available:

```
std::cout << ((person *)val) [i].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works. But how do you know the size of the array ?

```
void callback(void* p)
{

    Person* person = static_cast<Person*>(p);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << person[i].age_m << "\n";
}
```